# A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. In super call

Tags: typescript

Code:

```
export class NumberInput extends HTMLElement {

  constructor(...args: any) {

    super(...args);
```

Error log :

```
Error TS2556: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
(anonymous) @ example.js:1
```

Any suggestion! thanks

Comment: Give it the type `ConstructorParameters<typeof HTMLElement>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, as CaTS says it, `ConstructorParameters` is the way to go.

```
export class NumberInput extends HTMLElement {

    constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof HTMLElement>) {
        super(...args);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DkCuBbAI2CgEkA7MHeUGYMgE0wAkAVAWQBkBRJYPO%20AG8AsACgxcSYghk0MKDgQxoACgB0GlFADmaAFxwAwjLkKl0AApaU-WlDQAeGAE8wwCADM4rTjz4CAPgBKOBFRKQi4NBw3KHVNHTQggG4JKQBfMXSgA)